# Match everything until last presence of a character

Tags: regex

I have the following URL structure:

```
http://domain.com/images/1/10/104/104901/7.jpg
```

How can I match this with regex only until the last `/` slash to return this one?

```
http://domain.com/images/1/10/104/104901/
```

Thank You for your help!

Correction: I use Javascript.

Comment: (Without regex: Mirror the string, find the first slash, drop everything up to that, mirror the string again.)

Comment: @arkascha Unfortunately, no luck with this: http://regexr.com/3dg17

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?

Comment: @anubhava It's javascript's `.match()` method.

Comment: What do you mean, "no luck"? It does match and it does extract as required. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript you can use greedy match for this to match till last `/`:

```
/^.+\//
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regexr.com/3dg1a)

Alternatively you can do replacement of part after last `/`:

```
var s = 'http://domain.com/images/1/10/104/104901/7.jpg'
var r = s.replace(/[^/]+$/, '')
//=> "http://domain.com/images/1/10/104/104901/"
```

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the language.

But for Python you might be able to get away with a regex of `.+/`

But that's just a quick test (I won't guarantee the robustness of it).

[Here is it in action (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/iL0oE5/1).

With a slight change you can get it to pass [the regular expression site you were using](http://regexr.com/3dg1g).

```
.+\/
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use regular expressions, you could just mirror the string and find that first slash as others have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

An ES6 alternative without use of regular expressions would be to use `String.prototype.substring` and `String.prototype.lastIndexOf` :

```
myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

So, why should you use that ?

```
var myString = 'http://domain.com/images/1/10/104/104901/7.jpg';
console.time("With regex");
console.log(myString.replace(/[^/]+$/, ''));
console.timeEnd("With regex");                   // outputs 0.94ms
console.time("With String methods");
console.log(myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf('/')));
console.timeEnd("With String methods");          // outputs 0.53ms
```

Benchmark done on Firefox on my computer, but results should be similar everywhere.